# Mask for procedural objects on plane

Tags: node-editor, geometry, procedural

I have a plane with two objects distributed procedural. I use a random scale and objects going beyond the plane's borders. I want to restrict objects to only plane. I tried to use a mask by cube on the plane, but it did not work. I tried to realize the plane with procedural objects and make the Mesh Boolean node, but it is not working too. Can you help me how can I do it?[image]

UPD: I tried to make it by the comment below from @GordonBrinkmann, and the mask doesn't apply on the scaled objects but applies on the plane [image][image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you setup the _Boolean_ modifier? As you guessed, you have to realize the instances. Then you need a cube which covers the area you want to keep, then add a _Boolean_ modifier, set it to _Intersect_, and if you have enabled _Solver_ > _Exact_, you also need to check _Self Interpolation_ in the _Solver Options_. With my few objects it already takes quite a while to see the result, it works much faster if you set the _Solver_ to _Fast_ (as the name suggests), but then your objects will be open on the sides where they are cropped - if that's okay, use _Fast_.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Oh, my Blender crushes every time when I tried to make the boolean. If I correctly understood I need to add the boolean for the plane and select the cube as an object mask?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Oh, I did it, but it doesn't apply on the generated scaled objects on the plane, can you check please the new screenshots above? I make the realize for all geometry but it looks like it don't work and no idea why not(

Comment: Where in the screenshot is your cube-mask object? I cannot see where it is and what dimensions it has or where its boundaries are. Because the settings seem to be correct, with these settings it works for me.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Please check new screenshots, yes it works but not for all geometry) Don't understand this behavior

Comment: I don't understand either. In my Blender it works immediately. But the _Fast_ solver is made to be fast, not necessarily accurate. Maybe you should rather add the modifier to the board, not the cube? And do you have the same problem with the _Exact_ solver as well? Perhaps it is better if you upload your file and add it to the question: https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Ok Thank you I will try but my blender is down when I use the Exact solver)) Thank you!

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I added the file, thank you for your time!

Comment: _Exact_ solver with your file takes very very long on my computer, too. But it gets the correct result in my case. So far I found out the first and second _Instance on Points_ node are generating mesh that does not get cropped, the third is fine. I guess it's simply too much for the _Fast_ solver. It gets a bit better if you put the _Boolean_ modifier on the board instead of the cube, but all in all I guess it is just too much geometry. I wouldn't say 280,000 vertices is that much for a 3D object, but for _Boolean_ operations maybe... my object has 64,000 and the _Exact_ solver is struggling.

Comment: Notice that one of the objects (instance) has inverted normal. Fast can do if you correct that. But for the other one, no...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Ok, thank you for so huge help! Can you suggest please, where can I find your file, can't find it on the page..

Comment: @maxfry My file is nowhere because I uploaded it nowhere. It was just a bunch of randomly thrown together pieces with simple geometry, nothing special.

Comment: @lemon I corrected the normals on the instanced objects after I downloaded the file, but still it didn't work correctly.

Comment: Yes, @GordonBrinkmann, that worked only for one of the instance.

Comment: Thank you, guys!